# Let $G$ be a finite group such that for any two subgroups $H$ and $K$ either $H ⊆ K$ or $K ⊆ H$. Prove that $G$ is cyclic of prime power order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I do not understand how to approach this question. I cannot see why if any two subgroups of $G$ that are subsets of each other one way or another, it leads to $G$ being a cyclic group. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the Sylow's Theorems may work.

Comment: What happens in case, the group is trivial(finiteness includes this as well)? It is a cyclic group of non-prime order but satisfies the above conditions. So it must be non-trivial finite group. Please throw light on this.

Comment: is the converse of  this also true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for anything as high powered as the Sylow theorems. First, we show $G$ is cyclic. Fix $x \in G$ with maximal order among elements of $G$. For any $y \in G$, we have $\langle y \rangle \subseteq \langle x \rangle$ or $\langle x \rangle \subseteq \langle y \rangle$. By hypothesis, $|y| \leqslant |x|$, so $|\langle y \rangle| \leqslant |\langle x \rangle|$. If $|\langle y \rangle| < |\langle x \rangle|$, then the only possibility is $\langle y \rangle \subseteq \langle x \rangle$. If $|\langle y \rangle| = |\langle x \rangle|$ and $\langle x \rangle \subseteq \langle y \rangle$, then in fact we must have $\langle y \rangle = \langle x \rangle$, whence $\langle y \rangle \subseteq \langle x \rangle$. Hence, every $y \in G$ belongs to $\langle x \rangle$, whence $G = \langle x \rangle$ and is therefore cyclic.

Now, suppose $|G|$ has more than one prime divisor, say $p$ and $q$, seeking a contradiction. Then $|G|$ has an element $g$ of order $p$ and an element $h$ of order $q$, since $G$ is cyclic. Then $\langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle$ has order $1$ by Lagrange's theorem, and hence cannot be all of $\langle h \rangle$ or $\langle g \rangle$, contradicting our hypothesis that either $\langle h \rangle \subseteq \langle g \rangle$ or $\langle g \rangle \subseteq \langle h \rangle$. Hence, $|G|$ must be a prime power.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that every finite group out there is cyclic?

Comment: You said that "If |⟨y⟩|<|⟨x⟩|, then the only possibility is ⟨y⟩⊆⟨x⟩" shouldn't we say that ⟨y⟩ is a proper subset of ⟨x⟩ instead?

Comment: @Malush: for your first question, no. What part of this proof makes you say that? The property in the title of your post is quite strong, and is used extensively here. Most finite groups do not have this property. For your second question, one could, but it doesn't affect the argument of this proof, so do so if you like.

Comment: For instance if we take Z_20 we would have a cyclic group with subgroups but the order of 20 is not a prime power order is it?

Comment: @Malush: again, $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ does not satisfy the property in the title post. For example, if $H = \langle [4]_{20} \rangle, K = \langle [5]_{20} \rangle$, then neither $H$ nor $K$ contains the other. You should reread my proof to see why I picked this $H$ and $K$, and try to understand how the property is being used in the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach: First of all, the group is Abelian. If $x,y$ are two different elements, then either $x\in \langle y\rangle$ or $y\in\langle x \rangle$, and $x$ commutes with $y$.

By the fundamental theorem of finitely generated Abelian groups, $G$ is a direct sum of cyclic $p$-subgroups for some primes $p$. But if there is more than one group in the sum, then it is obvious that the subgroups are not linearly ordered. (Given $G=H\oplus K$, consider $1\oplus K$ and $H\oplus 1$).  Therefore there is only a cyclic factor of prime power order describing the entire group.

---

As another alternative, consider that picking an element $x$ of maximal order forces $G\subseteq\langle x\rangle$. Otherwise $y\notin \langle x\rangle$ implies $\langle y\rangle$ properly contains $\langle x\rangle$ contradicting the maximality of the order of $x$.

Now, if you are familiar with the fact that a cyclic group contains an element of each order dividing the group order, you can see that two different primes $p,q$ dividing the order would result in two subgroups that are impossible to linearly order. Therefore you are left with a cyclic $p$-group.

Comment: Nice first approach! Though I think you'll find that your second approach is identical to the one I posted above.

Comment: If you're interested, I gave another alternative, notably for the second part :)

Comment: @AlexWertheim Ultimately yes, but I felt like you were working too hard to explain why $G$ is cyclic, and I thought this was a good way to say it.

Comment: Essentially all the solutions I see here riff in the same thing: mechanism to show $G$ is cyclic, mechanism to show $G$'s order isn't divisible by two primes.

Comment: @rschwieb: that's fair, though I wouldn't consider what I said excessively long. At any rate, no disrespect meant.

Comment: @AlexWertheim none taken and none given on my part, I hope!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose two distinct primes $p$ and $q$ divide the order of $G$. Then, by Cauchy's theorem, $G$ has subgroups of order $p$ and $q$, which are not contained in one another.

Therefore $|G|$ is divisible by at most one prime $p$.

Let $x_0\in G$; if $\langle x_0\rangle\ne G$, then there is $x_1\in G$, $x_1\notin\langle x_0\rangle$; by the assumption we must have $\langle x_0\rangle\subsetneq\langle x_1\rangle$.

Complete the argument using finiteness of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

**$G$ is cyclic:** Because a finite group of order $n$ is cyclic iff it has at most one subgroup of order $d$ for all $d\mid n$. ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups#Finite_cyclic_groups))

**$n$ is a prime power:** $G$ has a unique maximal subgroup $M$ which has order $n/q$, where $q$ is a (the smallest) prime divisor of $n$. So $G\setminus M$ consists of generators. There are $\varphi(n)$ generators, so
$$\varphi(n)\geq n-\frac nq=n\cdot\frac{q-1}q.$$

But
$$\varphi(n)=n\cdot\prod_{p\mid n}\frac{p-1}p\leq n\cdot\frac{q-1}q,$$
so $n$ has only one prime divisor.

Comment: I didn't see that second half coming.. That is quite different from everything else floated.